# Why is BeanUtils.copyProperties dependency of spring not working?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-lombok-plugin

```java
@Table(name = "obj")
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Audited(name = "Obj")
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class Obj {
//PROPERTIES
}
```

`BeanUtils.copyProperties` is not working to copy the associations for this entity. It is unable to find getters and setters even when they get automatically defined using `@Data` of Lombok.

Comment: Are you getting exceptions?  What exactly do you get?

Comment: It will not recursivly copy properties, so complex objects aren't copied. Also copying an entity is probably a bad idea anyway. The `BeanUtils` is mainly for internal framework usage.

Comment: BeanUtils.copyProperties isnot able to find the getter and setters, which are already defined using Lombok. Susan Mustafa